# How nvme partition really work?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, fdisk, nvme

My goal is to delete my windows os from my disk.

So with `fdisk -l` command I see my disk partition:

```
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  527337471 526770176 251,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 998576128 1000214527   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 527337472  998576127 471238656 224,7G Linux filesystem
```

Great, in order to delete `/dev/nvme0n1p3` I do `sudo fdisk /dev/nvme0n1p3`, `p` to get some data about the partition and my terminal display this

```
Device           Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p3p1      2021161080 4042322159 2021161080 963,8G 78 unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p3p2      2021161080 4042322159 2021161080 963,8G 78 unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p3p3      4294932600 8589899894 4294967295     2T 78 unknown
/dev/nvme0n1p3p4      4294967295 5035196669  740229375   353G ff BBT
```

I really don't understand this, why my partition have sub-partitions, why sizes are ridiculously big ?  How can I learn more about ?

I look on Arch Wiki and Google but nothing relevant

Comment: I'd recommend that you keep Windows, as you'll need it for things like BIOS updates, etc., and running Windows apps for which there are no Linux counterparts. You can probably shrink the Windows partition, if you need to.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't shrink it, I will use VM if someday I need to use a Windows exclusive software

Comment: A VM won't let you do BIOS/firmware updates.